# Handling SPA Updates with Cache Busting - Dealing with partially loaded pages

Tags: vuejs3, single-page-application, vite, browser-cache

I'm working on a (static) Single Page Application using Vue3 and Vite communicating with a RestAPI, and I've enabled cache busting to ensure that clients always receive the latest/matching versions of my assets (when updating). However, I'm facing an issue where users who are on the old version of the SPA and have not loaded all files when navigating to pages that haven't been loaded yet.

Here's the scenario:

1. A user visits my SPA when it's running an older version.
2. They navigate to a few pages but haven't loaded all the assets.
3. I deploy a new version of the SPA by replacing the docker containers.
4. the user tries to navigate to pages that they haven't previously visited (and therefore haven't loaded), they encounter a stuck SPA since it can't load the missing modules

My questions are:

- What's the best practice for handling such situations ?
- How can I ensure that the SPA automatically refreshes itself/purges the browser cache?
- Are there any patterns or techniques I should follow when working with cache-busted assets in SPAs to avoid these issues?

I'm looking for guidance on how to handle this gracefully and ensure a smooth user experience during updates, especially for users who may have cached old assets. Since currently they need to forcefully refresh their cache (if the even know how to resolve the issue when subpages are not loading). Any help or insights are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Usually in SPAs you turn on HTTP browser caching for files such as images, JavaScript and CSS. For HTML files however, you explicitly disable browser caching. One way to manage this is to write code similar to this in the web host, which is the approach I use in [my SPA code sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/webhost/src/securityHeaders.ts#L53).

```js
private _getCacheControlResponseHeader(request: Request): string {

    const fullUrl = `${request.protocol}://${request.hostname}${request.originalUrl.toLowerCase()}`;
    const path = new URL(fullUrl).pathname;
    const extensions = [
        '.js',
        '.css',
        '.ico',
    ];

    const cacheableExtension = extensions.find((ext) => {
         return path.endsWith(`${ext}`);
    });

    if (cacheableExtension) {
        return 'public, max-age=31536000, immutable';
    } else {
        return 'no-cache, must-revalidate';
    }
}
```

The result is that every time the app loads, it requests the HTML file from the server, which usually returns a 304 not modified response. When the HTML file is upgraded, this downloads a new version of the HTML file, which contains cache busting timestamps for other resources, as below. The result should be reliable end-to-end deployments:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no'>

        <base href='/spa/' />
        <title>OAuth Demo App</title>

        <link rel='stylesheet' href='bootstrap.min.css?t=1696156680953' integrity='sha256-r5XY+61xZLKtKXLNHBmCfLfQqRnhOud395lWucqjb14='>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='app.css?t=1696156680953' integrity='sha256-uyU8ojtDL+l+a2gYIn6fJNKuwi2m7ChSCAWFFbLwbO0='>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='root' class='container'></div>

        <script type='module' src='vendor.bundle.js?t=1696156680953' integrity='sha256-y4lP6kSpQAYMK/JBVAlqd+KwJlBRwEDdNa+65dAl3KQ='></script>
        <script type='module' src='react.bundle.js?t=1696156680953' integrity='sha256-s1s4k0BQ4xzfj26zPL9hw5kmxy4LmhVKRZ2feeMRIZs='></script>
        <script type='module' src='app.bundle.js?t=1696156680953' integrity='sha256-QYKFWFQbgrGAR1kAVrVOID67fZ3igHR/Ob2XVgtI1Co='></script>
    </body>
</html>
```